# One device does not show on Google Play

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, google-play-store, multiple-devices

I just purchased two identical Android tablet for my kids, running ICS 4.0, both using the same gmail account. I have the Google Play store installed on both of them, but only one of them show on my Devices list on Google Play. I could not find a way to make the second device show on the site.

As I said, they are using the same gmail account and sharing the same site-specific password (as I use two-factor authentication). What can I do to make the second device show on the Device list so I can send app to both of them?

Persio